# Cannot send message using exchange in node-amqp

Tags: javascript, node.js, amqp, node-amqp

This is my code:

```
var amqp = require('amqp');

var connection = amqp.createConnection( { host: 'localhost' },  { defaultExchangeName: 'testexchange' });
connection.on('ready', function () {
  console.log('Connected to rabbitmq');
  var exchange = connection.exchange('testexchange', {confirm:true}, function(exch){
    console.log('Created exchange: ' + exch.name);
    var queue = connection.queue('testqueue', { durable: true }, function(q) {
      exch.publish('testqueue', {a:1}, {}, function(error) {
        console.log(error); 
      });
    });
  });
});
```

I'm using node 0.10.2 and node-amqp 0.1.6,

I can see `textexchange` by `rabbitmqctl list_exchanges` , but there's no `testqueue` by `rabbitmqctl list_queues`, what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define it first.

`connection.queue('testqueue', { durable: true })`

Comment: I've updated source. I can see `testqueue` now by `rabbitmqctl list_queues`, but there's no message in `testqueue`.

Comment: If you're not using the "direct" exchange you have to bind the exchange to the queue: ```queue.bind(exchange, routing_key)```